# Scala Constructor/Method Parameter Checking

Tags: scala

I wanted to check some best practices of Scala programming, since I am new to Scala. I read online about how Scala doesn't typically use exceptions except for "exceptional" circumstances (which doesn't include parameter checking). Right now in my project I am using a lot of `require`, so I am wondering what the better way of type checking would be.

For example, if I have a class

```
class Foo(String bar){
  require(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(bar), "bar can't be empty")
}
```

what are my alternatives to checking bar? Do I create a companion object like so

```
Object Foo {
  def apply(bar: String) = Try[Foo] {
    bar match = {
      case null => Failure("can't be null")
      //rest of checks
      case _ => Success[Foo]
  }
}
```

Or should I use Option instead?

In addition, for scala methods, how do I check the parameter of the method? If I already return an Option, do I just return an empty Option if I get a bad parameter? Wouldn't that mean I have to check for an empty Option when I use the return of the method and wouldn't throwing an exception allow for a more specific message? (e.g. runtime exception can't use nulls).

Comment: i too wonder about this

Comment: @eddiemundorapundo how would that work for methods? For classes I would just use apply right?

Comment: ugh sorry for deleting my comment I hadn't seen Try/Success/Failure since I last used Scala.
Try/Success/Failure seems to be like Either which is like Option.

In your example looks like you'd have to getOrElse() in conjunction with your Foo() to get a Foo object or you could do something with the Foo object directly by using Foo().flatMap(...) and return yet another Try (which could come from your methods) then chain more maps/filters/whatevers.

Comment: @eddiemundorapundo no problem, mapping is still valid for options iirc! :) I could just handle it on the side when I create it, but that just seems like extra work- that's why I was wondering if it would be better to just use `requires`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Success part of your companion object would return the Foo() object as well?

```
    Object Foo {
      def apply(bar: String) = Try[Foo] {
        bar match = {
          case null => Failure("can't be null")
          //rest of checks
          case _ => Success[Foo](new Foo(bar))
        }
    }
```

To use it you might do something with the `Success` you get from Foo(bar):

```
    val hehe = Foo(bar).map(foo => foo.someString()).getOrElse('failed')
```

The Try methods will automatically wrap exceptions generated by someString() or whatever else that you're doing inside it inside Failures. If you wanted to check the parameters of `foo.someString()`, you'd do something similar to your `apply()` method. It isn't that much different than throwing exceptions on conditions but I think it's nicer cause the "catch blocks" would be in `recover()` or `recoverWith()`. You can always exit the `Try` using `getOrElse()` if your code wasn't designed to chain `Try`s from top to bottom.

Comment: Whoops yeah, meant to have it return a new foo object too. So when I want to create a new Foo object, `val hehe = Foo(bar)` will give me a Failure if I pass in a bad variable, and a Success otherwise? What is `someString()`?

Comment: Oh sorry `someString()` is just an example method that `foo` might have. Yes when `bar` is `null` `Foo(bar)` will return a `Failure` which is an instance of `Try` which has methods like `map()`. When you use methods such as `map()` on a `Failure` it'll return that same `Failure`. So you can kind of think of it like a pipeline where when some part of the pipe returns a `Failure`, all further parts of the pipe will pass that `Failure` along. Wherever you want to handle the failure in the pipeline is where you can put `recover()` or `recoverWith()`.